# Is it safe to move C:\Users and add a symbolic link\junction?

Tags: windows, symbolic-link

I am using Windows 8.1 and the `Users` directory has got a bit big (22.2Gb).

I'd like to move it off the SSD and onto the massive HDD.  Is it safe to replace is with a symbolic link from the SSD to the directory on the HDD?